# COBOL Unstring into an Array

Tags: arrays, string, input, record, cobol

I'm trying to unstring my input-line which is seperated with ";", into an array. But i'm having trouble with displaying every word after the first ";".

So basically, Input: Hello;Stack;Overflow

---

Output: Value: 2  (because of 2 semicolons)

---

Line 1 of my Record Table: Hello

---

Line 2 of my Record Table: Stack

---

Line 3 of my Record Table: Overflow

My code so far:

```
*-------------------------------------------------------------
 LINKAGE SECTION.                                             
 01  X-INPUT-LINE                   PIC X(2000).              
 01  X-SEP-CHAR                     PIC X(1).                                     
 01  X-RET-TABLE.                                             
  02 CMAX                           PIC 9(5) COMP-3.          
  02 ENTRY-REC OCCURS 0 TO 9999 TIMES DEPENDING ON CMAX       
                                      INDEXED   BY CIDX.      
   04 ENTRY-REC2.                                             
    07 LINEVALUE                    PIC X(100).               

PROCEDURE DIVISION USING X-INPUT-LINE
                         X-SEP-CHAR  
                         X-RET-TABLE.

MAIN SECTION.
MN-00.       
INITIALIZE WERT.                                

INSPECT X-INPUT-LINE TALLYING WERT FOR ALL      
        X-SEP-CHAR.                             
MOVE X-INPUT-LINE TO VAL.                       

ADD 1 TO WERT.                                  
PERFORM WERT TIMES                              
MOVE WERT TO LINEVALUE OF X-RET-TABLE (WERT)    
     UNSTRING VAL DELIMITED BY ";"              
     INTO STRVAL                                
     END-UNSTRING                               


IF CMAX OF X-RET-TABLE < 9999                   
   ADD  1  TO CMAX OF X-RET-TABLE               
   MOVE STRVAL TO ENTRY-REC(CMAX OF X-RET-TABLE)

END-IF                                          
END-PERFORM.
```

With my following code I can only display the "Hello" in my example and the program displays it 3 times in 3 different rows.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve], at best one that is compileable...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original code *nearly* works.

The main issue is, that you `UNSTRING` a given variable and always use the same starting point.

He we can use `WITH POINTER`. Used on `STRING` the clause says "position where next character is stored", used on `UNSTRING` it says "position where next character is read from".

Using the starting code (added the caller, actually use the given separator instead of the fixed ";" and a `DISPLAY` of the result), added [here](http://tpcg.io/JvoqEi) we add a variable for the starting point and use it.

```
     UNSTRING X-INPUT-LINE DELIMITED BY X-SEP-CHAR
     INTO STRVAL
     END-UNSTRING
```

becomes

```
     UNSTRING X-INPUT-LINE DELIMITED BY X-SEP-CHAR
     INTO STRVAL
     WITH POINTER STARTING-POINT
     END-UNSTRING
```

You'll also need to initialize some parts and can directly use the table item (as long as you ensure the counter doesn't get too big), providing you with the [result](http://tpcg.io/PyBgPQ) (includes more samples).

Comment: Hi @Simon Sobisch Firstly, I never knew that we can use coding ground for Cobol to call sub programs. Thanks for the awareness. Great answer though.

Comment: @SrinivasanJv The easiest way is to combine everything to a single compilation unit like I did (using `END PROGRAM`). When you "Share" on coding ground you always share the project which may consist of multiple sources. To make multiple sources to work you have to adjust the compilation command (easiest: change to `cobc -m *.cob` and the run command to `cobcrun yourmain`).

Comment: Good ideas. Not sure why you do the if statement: IF WERT < 9999.... Also the INSPLECT before may not be required if you do the PERFOM until pointer >= string length.

Answer (score 1):

Unstring doesn't really work that way. Unstring will work if you know the field names of the what you want to unstring into. Basically what is happening in your code is you run the unstring 3 times and because "hello" is the first thing in the unstring it is being unstrung 3 times. If you want to do something scalable into an array, you would need to code a loop like this:

```
01 WS-UNSTRING-FIELDS.
   05 WS-INPUT PIC X(1000).
   05 WS-SUB   PIC 9(4) COMP.
   05 WS-START PIC 9(4) COMP VALUE 1.
   05 WS-INDEX PIC 9(4) COMP VALUE 0.
   05 WS-ARRAY OCCURS 0 TO 9999 DEPENDING ON WS-INDEX.

PERFORM VARYING WS-SUB
           FROM 1 BY 1 
          UNTIL WS-SUB > FUNCTION LENGTH(WS-INPUT)
   IF WS-INPUT(WS-SUB:1) = ";"
      ADD 1 TO WS-INDEX

      MOVE WS-INPUT(WS-START:WS-SUB - 1) 
        TO WS-ARRAY(WS-INDEX)

      COMPUTE
         WS-START = WS-SUB + 1
      END-COMPUTE
   END-IF
END-PERFORM
```

I haven't really had time to test this and ensure it works 100%, but you would need something along those lines. I would avoid using unstring here at any rate.

Unstring works great when you know exactly how many fields are coming in. Like for instance, lets say you have generic program that interacts with MQ series. As input to this program, you can pass a string that holds instructions something like

```
QueueName/Action
```

you could then use unstring in this context to split them into 2 fields:

```
UNSTRING WS-INPUT DELIMITED BY "/"
   INTO WS-Q-NAME
        WS-ACTION
END-UNSTRING
```

Lets say the input here was:

```
THIS_IS_MY_QUEUE/DELETE
```

WS-Q-NAME would have THIS_IS_MY_QUEUE_NAME and WS-ACTION would have DELETE

Comment: How about using `UNSTRING` in the loop along the lines of `MOVE INPUT TO REMIANDER` , then `PERFORM UNTIL REMAINDER = ''` with `UNSTRING REMAINDER [...] INTO ARRAY(IND) REMAINDER`

Comment: What exactly would WS-Sub or WS-Start be in my source code, I can't really relate to ur answer.

Comment: @Brian WS-SUB is just an index that increments so you can check the string 1 character at a time. WS-START is just keep track of where the first character is after each delimiter.

Comment: @piet.t that would be another option. Personally, I like the idea of a substring loop better. I find it easier to understand exactly how its working. But looping through the substring is an option

Comment: @piet.t @SaggingRufus A point to be noted while using `UNSTRING` is that it copies characters from source string to the destination until a condition is met which terminates the data movement (in this case, it's ';'). So, `PERFORM UNTIL REMAINDER = ' '` with `UNSTRING REMAINDER INTO ARRAY(IND) REMAINDER` will result in an endless loop as `ARRAY(1)` would contain 'Hello' and `REMAINDER` would contain 'STACK'. When data movement ends for a ARRAY(1), the next destination string, REMAINDER becomes the receiving area & characters are copied until once again a terminating condition is met.

Comment: Hi @SaggingRufus your code need another `SUB` data item say `WS-SUB1`, which has to be renewed to zero everytime a ';' is met and +1ed until another ';' so that you can use this new data item in the `MOVE WS-INPUT(WS-START1:WS-SUB1 - 1) 
        TO WS-ARRAY(WS-INDEX)` statement. This ensures correct length of the string being moved to the array.  Also required is an `IF` condition to move the last portion 'Overflow' of the source string, which isn't delimited by ';'. Updated code is here (http://tpcg.io/BQ3MJO).